# Wordpress with Docker-compose not getting environment variables

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

The `docker-compose` file contains standard wordpress settings. DB and nginx service blocks are left out for brevity.

```
  image: wordpress:6.1.1-php8.2-fpm
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: user
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_WP_HOME: http://example.com
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: >
          define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.com/');
          define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/');
          define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
    volumes:
      - wp-app:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - wordpress-network
```

I expected the variables `WP_HOME` `WP_SITEURL` and `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` to be set in `/var/www/html/wp-config.php` inside the container.
But the values there are just the default values or blank.
Maybe these user variables get set somewhere else. But trying to locate them by
grep-ing the wordpress installation directory did not return any hits of the specific URL.

I tried different syntax like:

```
WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA=
    define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.com/');
```

or

```
WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: >
          define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.com/');
```

but still no success.
What is the correct way to add these environment variables to my wordpress setup?

Comment: It will not work because wp_home and wp_siteurl is already defined in the generated wp-config.php file. config extra will just append another two lines of the same definitions however the only the first will be taken. (already defined). try to go into container and look into your wp-config.php file. @theDrifter

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pipe "|" . Docker-compose will interpret this as multi-line string:

```
  WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
        define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.com/');
        define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/');
        define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
```

Comment: Hi i tried that but i got the same results. WP_Home is not set in /var/www/html/wp-config.php

Answer (score 0):

The `wp-config.php` file is no longer written to, rather its created at runtime ([reference](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/discussions/786#discussioncomment-4604876))

> The variables are not embedded into the file anymore -- they get
> loaded at runtime instead so that changes are applied correctly
> without any hacky file editing.

This is handy to see what env vars docker is using: `docker exec <name> printenv`